# check if Team exists in the database or the input field is empty

Tags: spring, rest, thymeleaf

It is necessary to check if the input fields for Team are empty, and whether there is such a Team in the repository.

If the field is not empty and there is no such Team, then you can create a new Team. If the field is empty or Team already exists, then give an error

AdminController

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/team", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String addTeam(Model model, @ModelAttribute("teamForm") @Validated TeamForm teamForm,
            BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        System.out.println("addTeam invoked");
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/admin";
        }
        Team newTeam = new Team();
        newTeam.setName(teamForm.getName());
        newTeam.setUrl(teamForm.getUrl());
        teamRepository.save(newTeam);
        return "teamList";
    }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("teamForm",new TeamForm());
        model.addAttribute("eventForm",new EventForm());
        model.addAttribute("usersForm",new UsersForm());
        return "admin";
    }
```

admin.html

```
      <form th:action="@{/admin/team}"
        th:object="${teamForm}" method="POST">
      Team name:
      <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
          <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Incorrect Name</p>
      <br/>
      Url :
      <input type="text" th:field="*{url}" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Create Team" />
  </form>
```